# Creating Boolean list from comparing 2 lists

Tags: python, list, filter, boolean

I have 2 lists I want to compare. List_A contains all the filenames I have, List B contains the filenames I want.

List_C being the output is a boolean list with the same length as List_A. Showing false for those files who can't be found in List_B and true for those who are found in List_B.

This is for filtering a list of elements, by boolean.

```
# Load the Python Standard and DesignScript Libraries
import sys
import clr
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *

# The inputs to this node will be stored as a list in the IN variables.
dataEnteringNode = IN

List_A = IN[0]
List_B = IN[1]



OUT = List_C

A scenario

List_A = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]

List_B = [x2, x3]

List_C = [false, true, true, false, false]
```

Comment: What did you try to solve it - where is the problem with your solution? Where is your solution -> [mre]? What good for are the imports and things in your shown code? What is `[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]` - those are `NameErrors` because they are variable names and you do not define them anywhere - same for `[x2, x3]`. Please [edit] your question, provide a minimal example and your code that has got problems. Show input and output and what does not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is mapping, not filtering, and it is a one-liner:

```
list(map(lambda x: x in List_B, List_A))
```

You could use a list comprehension,

```
[x in List_B for x in List_A]
```

but I personally find seeing `x in` in two different senses confusing.

Comment: This is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
List_C = [elem in List_B for elem in List_A]
```

That basically equals to a for loop that for every element of List_A appends result of `elem in List_B` to a new list.